# Adding a static method to an existing class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have I file containing:

```
module BlahA
   module BlahB
      class Note
         def some_method
         end
      end
   end
end
```

I would like to add a static method to the Note class so I add the following to another file

```
module BlahA
   module BlahB
      class Note
         def self.some_static_method
         end
      end
   end
end
```

When I try call it like

```
BlahA::BlahB::Note.some_static_method
```

I get

```
undefined method `some_static_method' for BlahA::BlahB::Note:Class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a static method, you would define it as

```
def self.some_static_method
  #something
end
```

And make sure `some_file.rb` is required in your file.

Comment: My bad, I had the `self.` in original code and left it out when simplifying. It still doesn't work with this modification however you are right so I up marked it

Comment: Next question would be is some_file.rb in your load path?

Comment: You got it... put your second comment into your answer and I will mark is as correct